# How to link between two different elements

Tags: java, dom, xpath, sax

in the below posted xml file, the element "tag" contains speed info. the problem i am facing is that, the first two elements "node"

```
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
```

their speed info is enclosed in the immediate proceeding two elements "tag"

```
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
```

and the second two element "node":

```
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.038904" lon="8.84614"/>
```

their speed info is enclosed in the immediate proceeding two elements "tag"

```
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
```

what i want to do is, given the information of the "lat" attribute, the speed information should be returned. for an example, if the input is either lat="53.0334062" or lat="53.0338904"
the returned values should be v="30".  and if the input is either lat="53.334062" or lat="53.038904 the returned values should be v="32"

how can i achive that using xpath?

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<node id="25779114" lat="53.334062" lon="8.841545"/>
<node id="25779117" lat="53.038904" lon="8.84614"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="32"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
</osm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
//node[@lat="53.0334062"]/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v

//node[@lat="**yourinput**"]/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v
```

explanation:

`node[@lat="53.0334062"]` matches your condition. then, `following-sibling` fetches all child's in the node element, within that elements it will select the first `tag` element, indeed that is the element you require to get the attribute `'V'`.